# Is the fractional part of a real number has to be greater than or equal to 0 but less than 1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part

I was reading the definition of **fractional part**, but I have not understood something and I want to make sure.

1. Is the fractional part of a real number has to be greater than or equal to 0 but less than 1?
2. What would happen if the fractional part of a number were greater or equal than 1?

My doubt arises because it mentions an interval, but I don't understand it well, **I'm new**

Comment: It's a matter of definition. the fractional part is always equal to the number less the greatest integer less than or equal to the number.  Such a thing could not be as great as $1$ (nor could it be less than $0$).

Comment: Hi @lulu so, will the fractional part of a real number **always** be greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1?

Comment: 1. Yes, that is part of the definition of "fractional part".  2. That would be some other function, not "fractional part".  It mentions an interval.  You are stating the definition of the half-open interval $[0,1)$.

Comment: hi @GEdgar, does [0,1) mean that the fractional part must be a real number greater than or equal to 0 but less than 1? I know my questions are very stupid but I am too new to mathematics.

Comment: You have it right.  For any real $x$, the fractional part of $x$, usually denoted $\{x\}$, must satisfy $0≤\{x\}<1$.  For positive real numbers, written in decimal form, the fractional part is found by just taking the part to the right of the decimal.  Thus $\{2.718281828\}=.718281828$, for example.

Comment: Yes.  The interval $[0,1)$ is the set of all real numbers $x$ that satisfy $x \ge 0$ and $x<1$.  The fractional part of a real number must be an element of the set $[0,1)$.

Comment: The fractional part represents **only a part** of a whole (of the whole unit), right? @GEdgar

Comment: Excellent @lulu, your example is good

Comment: The only question is how we define the fractional part for negative real numbers. PARI/GP outputs for example $0.3$ as the fractional part of $-1.7$. Apparently , the largest integer not exceeding the given number is subtracted from the given number. This fits to the intuitive result for positive real numbers where we just cut off the integer-part. To avoid problems arising from $0.\bar 9=1.\bar 0=1$ , integers are considered to have fractional part $0$.

Comment: Excellent, good complementary information. The fractional part represents **only a part** of a whole (of the whole unit), right? @Peter

Answer (score 1):

$\text{frac}(x)$ is defined to be $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$. Suppose we have a real number $x$. $x$ can be understood as an integer plus some more things that are too small to be represented as an integer.

[image]

Convention uses $\lfloor x\rfloor$ to represent this integer part, and $\text{frac}(x)$ to represent this fractional part. I think it is now clear where the formula $\text{frac}(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ come from.

Now to answer your questions.

> 1. Is it true that the fractional part of a real number has to be greater than or equal to $0$ but less than $1$?

Yes.

It can be equal to $0$ if $x$ is already an integer. For example, if we have $3$, It doesn't make sense to have a fractional part of $1$ and an integer part of $2$. The fractional part of $3$ is just $0$.

The fractional part can't be $1$ or greater than $1$ either. Remember that the fractional part is the "leftover bit that is too small to be represented as an integer". If we have $3.14$, it doesn't make sense to have a fractional part of $1.14$ and an integer part of $2$, since $1.14$ is big enough to be represented as $1$ and $0.14$. In this case, the integer part is $3$ and the fractional part is $0.14$. The fractional part must be smaller than 1.

> 2. What would happen if the fractional part of a number were greater or equal than 1?

As I've said above, this can't happen.

Now to understand why the inventors of Math defined so, suppose that the fractional part can be greater than $1$. Then, the fractional part of $3.14$ can be $0.14$, $1.14$, $2.14$ or just $3.14$. When a function has multiple values, it basically renders the function useless.